# Upgrade file only working on localhost

Tags: magento-1.7, attributes, sql, localhost, upgrade-script

I have a file named `upgrade-1.0.3-1.0.4.php` under `CSB/Customer/sql/csb_customer_setup`, and I updated the code in config.xml, under `CSB/etc`, to `<version>1.0.4</version>`.

On localhost the upgrade is working fine. However, when I put the files in the server the upgrade is not working. I already deleted the content of `var/cache`.

In PhpMyAdmin, I found a table named `core_resource` which has the entry CSB_customer_setup set to 1.0.4, both on localhost and on the server. I don't know exactly what this entry is, but at least the value is the last one I defined.

I don't see why in the server it's not working. Any ideas? All help is appreciated.

Edit: here's my code for `config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <CSB_Customer>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </CSB_Customer>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <CSB_customer>
                <class>CSB_Customer_Helper</class>
            </CSB_customer>
        </helpers>
        <resources>
            <CSB_customer_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>CSB_Customer</module>
                    <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </CSB_customer_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <CSB_customer>
                    <file>CSB_customer.xml</file>
                </CSB_customer>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <CSB_Customer>
                    <files>
                        <default>CSB_Customer.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </CSB_Customer>
            </modules>
        </translate>
        <routers>
            <customer>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <CSB_customer before="Mage_Customer">CSB_Customer</CSB_customer>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </customer>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

The row in `core_resource` is added when you have entry inside `config.xml`.If no setup file exists (or it is in the wrong place) magento just creates the row in the core_resource table and doesn't call any script.

This is a problem if you later add a install-script, which is never called, because the entry already exists.

So You can do below thing -

1. Check you have uploaded script file at right place.
2. You can change your module's setup version in `core_resource` table to the previous version .
3. refresh any page and check your upgrade table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just tried changing the value in core_resource to 1.0.3, cleared cache and refreshed page. The value becamse again 1.0.4, but the upgrade is still not taking place. I already verified that the script is in the right place. Would it be okay if I delete my files named upgrade in the server, and I put a new one called install-1.0.0.php, and I remove the entry from core-resource? Would that do the work, and would there be any problem?

Comment: if your file is at right place and still your upgrade is not working then you should check your code in script.

Answer (score -2):

check for errors in **var/log/system.log** and **var/log/exception.log**

Comment: Just checked and I see no errors related to my issue

Comment: It must be because I see entries from some minutes ago. Anyway, where can I turn it on/off? Thank you for answering.